# FUSE- logging file opened time - File System

Tags: filesystems, fuse

With FUSE API, is it possible to know that for how much time a file is opened. If yes, then which methods to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to implement open and release, then use the fuse info structure (depending on your implementation) to correlate the two.

Comment: release is called when a file is closed?

Comment: That's correct.  So if you create a timestamp when it's opened, and then compare when release is called, you can figure out how long it's been open.  I don't know exactly how accurate it is (probably not to the millisecond), but it should be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: I tried that but there seems some thing wrong with my code. the problem with my File System is that when i open a file OPEN method is called and immediately RELEASE method is also called without closing the file and the opened file then shows this error message http://s29.postimg.org/9nn7xfqw7/Untitled.png  . [I explained it here in detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595823/fuse-example-file-system-the-file-changed-on-disk-do-you-want-to-reload-the-fi), I would be greatful if you answer